# Change the setting of Reviews to not need approval from BE

Tags: magento-1.9, review, ratings

What is the best way to disable reviews moderation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overwrite `Mage_Review_ProductController` controller `postAction` function.

Here Review is added like below:

```
$review->setEntityId($review->getEntityIdByCode(Mage_Review_Model_Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE))
->setEntityPkValue($product->getId())
->setStatusId(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_PENDING)
->setCustomerId(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId())
->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
->setStores(array(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()))
->save();
```